# Can't get custom scrollbar jquery plugin (tiny scrollbar) to work on another gallery plugin (galleria)

Tags: jquery

Been at this for a while. Trying to add a custom scroll bar to the photo gallery (customized Jquery galleria plugin) on expression engine, but no matter what I do it doesn't seem to work.

The site is live at www.pleasuredoingbusiness.org, and it's the collections page that i'm having trouble with. Galleria works fine, and i've modified the tinyscrollbarcolgal.js file so that it creates the appropriate divs/classes for tiny scroll bar. But it doesn't load up the javascript for some reason

galleria creates .galleria-container which is what i'm targeting with the tiny scrollbar plugin.

I've tried to load the custom scrollbar with $(window).load instead of $(document).ready, which got it to finally show up, but only if you refresh the page. (on chrome) On IE it still just doesn't show up at all

I've also tested with another custom scrollbar plugin and got the same results. Doesn't show unless i do $(window).load instead of $(document).ready, but only works if you refresh it. I've actually thought of maybe forcing it to refresh/load just once, couldn't get that to work (it kept looping), and the refresh thing doesn't seem to work on ie either.

Can anyone help!!?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've been trying to do the same thing.  I think you need to target $('.galleria-thumbnails') rather than .galleria-container.  But I still haven't had much luck, so I may be wrong about that.